# AWS VPN Client connection to new VPC Endpoint is failing

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, openvpn, amazon-vpc, cidr

I have set up a new VPN following the guide [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-admin/cvpn-getting-started.html). However when I try to connect to the VPN with the client i get an error "Connection failed. Try again." This happens every time. I opened the log file from my AppData\Roaming\AWSVPNClient\logs folder and I spotted an error in the log. I have pasted the log below:

```
2020-04-23 15:32:52.088 +01:00 [INF] Starting OpenVpn process
2020-04-23 15:32:52.284 +01:00 [DBG] DeDupeProcessDiedSignals: Unexpected errors caused OpenVPN to exit prematurely
2020-04-23 15:32:52.284 +01:00 [ERR] Process died signal sent
ACVC.Core.OpenVpn.OvpnProcessFailedToStartException: Unexpected errors caused OpenVPN to exit prematurely
   at ACVC.Core.OpenVpn.OvpnWpfProcessManager.<Start>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at ACVC.Core.OpenVpn.OvpnConnectionManager.<Connect>d__58.MoveNext()
2020-04-23 15:32:52.284 +01:00 [DBG] Received exception for connection state Disconnected. Show error message to user
2020-04-23 15:32:52.284 +01:00 [ERR] Exception recieved by connect window view model
ACVC.Core.OpenVpn.OvpnProcessDiedException: The VPN process has stopped unexpectedly.
2020-04-23 15:39:07.769 +01:00 [DBG] Clean up connections. Connection state: Connecting
2020-04-23 15:39:07.769 +01:00 [INF] Terminating connection
2020-04-23 15:39:07.769 +01:00 [DBG]  Ending connection details reporting.
2020-04-23 15:39:07.769 +01:00 [DBG] GracefulKill
2020-04-23 15:39:07.769 +01:00 [DBG] Stopping openvpn process
2020-04-23 15:39:07.769 +01:00 [DBG] Cancelling socket listen token
2020-04-23 15:39:07.769 +01:00 [DBG] Dispose socket
2020-04-23 15:39:07.875 +01:00 [DBG] Release process manager lock
2020-04-23 15:39:07.875 +01:00 [DBG] Disconnected
```

I have Googled the exception but not found anything of use. I wonder if it could be that I set up the CIDR ranges incorrectly? That was the only part of the guide that confused me.

Any help is massively appreciated.

Comment: try to get the actual openvpn logs instead of the ones from the wrapper

Comment: where are those?

Comment: @DennisNolte: Yeah, where are those? :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, which I solved by reinstalling the AWS Client VPN software.
I checked the device driver and there was no TAP-Windows.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-user/windows-troubleshooting.html#windows-troubleshooting-client-vpn-quits

> **VPN connection process quits unexpectedly**
>
> **Problem**
>
> While connecting to a Client VPN endpoint, the client quits unexpectedly.
>
> **Cause**
>
> TAP-Windows is not installed on your computer. This software is required to run the client.
>
> **Solution**
>
> Rerun the AWS-provided client installer to install all the required dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

For me worked install a different version to the newest:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-user/release-notes.html

I installed 1.2.1 on a windows 10 machine

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error and the reason was that the `.ovpn`, `.crt` and `.key` files were moved. To fix this, you have to replace the missing files. For me, this was a simple moving the files back.

If this does not help you, then probably creating a new `.ovpn` file, fixing the paths to the `.crt` and `.key` files and creating a new profile in the application works.

Apparently, "File not found" is so '90s for AWS :-).

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. Im not sure for the answer but It connected!
In my case, I located configuration file at C:\User\username\configuration file 
so, I relocated configuration file at C:\configuration file 
try it!